# Angular Material data table showing table headers even when there is no data

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am using Angular material data table to show some product related data in a table with matSort for sorting. In the data table I've used `[hidden]="!data"` but when there is no data, I still get the table headers displaying. I tried wrapping it with ngIf directive, It worked, were the table header were not displaying when there is no data, but matSort stopped working.

```
<table mat-table [hidden]="!data" [dataSource]="data" matSort>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="productName">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Product Name </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.productName}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    ...
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

In short, I don't need the table header to be displayed when there is no data along with matSort working.

Comment: Well i guess that `data!==null`

Comment: If I use data!==null. Table is not showing any data at all.

Comment: That confirms what i wrote, `data!==null` therfore `!data` is always `false` which least to `hidden=false`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. In my case i solve this way.

component.html

```
<app-loading *ngIf="isLoading$ | async"></app-loading>
<div *ngIf="(isLoading$ | async) === false">
   <ng-container *ngIf="dataSource.data.length >= 1; else noData">
      <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 50]"></mat-paginator>
      <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        ...
      </mat-table>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-template #noData>
      <h3>Ops...</h3>
      <p>There is no data...</p>
   </ng-template>
</div>
```

and the component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
...
export class Component implements OnInit {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Use the ViewChild to bind the paginator and the sort to sync with server response async. Then pass set to be able to set async the values in paginator, sort or filter...

ngAfterViewInit() cycle will run right after the component init. And maybe be serve wont have response the data yet. As i said, in my case i could be fetch async the paginator async with the server response using set, take a look in https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Keep coding \m/